# Total amount of complete orders of a customer

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, collection

I'm trying to do the sum of the amount of all complete orders by a particular customer.
I write this to do so:

```
$collectionOrders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $email)->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete');
foreach ($collectionOrders as $order) {
    $total += $order->getGrandTotal();
}
echo $total . "\n";
```

But when i check in the admin section the orders, i find the value of is actually higher. I think i've got something wrong in the loop.

Comment: do you give any value for $total?? Like $total = 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this :

```
    <?php
    $total=0;
    $collectionOrders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$email)->addFieldToFilter('status','complete');
       foreach($collectionOrders as $order){
               $total += $order->getGrandTotal();
       }
        echo $total."\n";

?>
```

[See more here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41806/how-to-get-all-ordersand-orders-sum-for-current-customer)